# meaning of "drawing with them"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading *The Versions of Us* by Laura Barnett and there is a scene on the beach that goes:

> Jim reaches for Eva’s hand. Eva squeezes back, holding on; both of
>   **them** looking to the horizon, to where the great waves are breaking,
>   **drawing with them** the deep, unanswered loneliness of the open sea.

I'm confused about what the second "them" refers to. Does it refer to Jim and Eva or the great waves? Either way, what does "drawing with them" the loneliness of the sea means? Can anybody give me some clues?

Answer (score 1):

The second **them** in your passage refers to the **breaking waves**

In your excerpt

> **drawing with them** the deep, unanswered loneliness of the open sea

**them** refers to the **breaking waves**.  When waves break, they create an **undertow** which **pulls back** the water and anything in it back into the main body of water.

**Drawing** can be used to express **pulling** or **carrying**

> **drawing** water from a well

The movement that's being expressed here is the **action of the waves** pulling *(whatever it catches)* back down into the mysterious depths of the open sea

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted. This looks like a perfectly good answer.